# Install older version of a snap

Tags: software-installation, snap

I know updated snaps can be reverted back to a previously installed version but is it possible to install an older version of a snap in the first place?

For example, if the version of AmazingApp in the snap store is v1.3, is there a way to install v1.2?

Is there an archive?

Answer (score 4):

Snap Store has release channels. For example - [VLC player](https://snapcraft.io/vlc):

> [image: versions of VLC player]

So you can choose channel and install the respective version:

```
| Channel          | Version                 |  Install command                  |  
|------------------|-------------------------|-----------------------------------|
| latest/stable    | 3.0.6                   | sudo snap install vlc             |
| latest/candidate | 3.0.6                   | sudo snap install vlc --candidate |
| latest/beta      | 3.0.6-50-g71bfa08       | sudo snap install vlc --beta      |
| latest/edge      | 4.0.0-dev-6398-g44b30c2 | sudo snap install vlc --edge      |
```

For other Snaps this is completely dependent on Snap developer (which [channels](https://docs.snapcraft.io/channels/551) were created).

Comment: thanks, unfortunately all channels including stable had been updated to the latest version, I was wanting to install a previous version

Comment: @freddybob in that case, you'll have to contact the publisher to ask them to create a track for the version of the software you want.

Comment: This a bit of a painful design. After hunting down version bugs you then have to fit your requirements into the available channels. Channels are a great idea when your model is that everyone has a regimented pipeline to production. In science and machine learning it is very different.